# Ajax Call multiple time for same html class which is in array like this [ ]

Tags: php, html, ajax

my code is here

```
  <table    id="tb" width="100% style="float:left; overflow:auto">
    <tr >
        <th width="300px" style=" text-align: left; margin-left: 15px">Item</th>
                    <th width="300px" style=" text-align: left; margin-left: 15px">Description</th>
        <th width="100px" style="font-size: 60%">Average<br> Price</th>

        <th width="150px">Quantity</th>
        <th width="150px">Price</th>
        <th width="150px">Discount</th>
        <th width="200px">Amount</th>
        <th width="50px"></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="height: 35px">


        <td><select style="font-size: 100% ;padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 30px; display: inline-block; width: 100%" ntype="text" 
                                        class="form-control item" name="item[]" required  >
                                            <?php $this->load->view('f-select-item'); ?></td>

        <td><input style="font-size: 100% ;padding-left: 10px; height: 30px; display: inline-block; width: 100%" ntype="text" 
                                        class="form-control" name="item_note[]"  /></td>
                                                                                    <td class="priced"><input 
                                                                                    style="height: 30px; text-align: right" pattern="[0-9]+"  value=""
                                        maxlength="10" minlength="0"  min='0' max='50000000' type="text" name="price1[]"  class="form-control ppp" /></td>


        <td><input style="height: 30px;text-align: right"  id ="num" maxlength="10" minlength="0"  pattern="[0-9]+" type="text" name="quantity[]"  class="form-control quantity"  /></td>

                                        <td><input style="height: 30px; text-align: right" pattern="[0-9]+"  maxlength="10" minlength="0"  min='0' max='50000000' type="text" name="price[]"  class="form-control price" /></td>

                                        <td><input style="height: 30px;text-align: right" pattern="[0-9]+" maxlength="10" minlength="0"  type="text" name="discount[]"  class="form-control discount"  /></td>
                                        <td><input  style="height: 30px;text-align: right" type="text"  maxlength="30" minlength="0"  name="amount[]" 
                                        class="form-control amount" value="" readonly/></td>

                                        <td style="height: 25px;text-align:right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 80%; padding: 0 0 0 5; font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Row">
                <span style="font-size:80%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                </span>
            </a><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove' title="Remove Row">
                                            <span  style="padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align:right; color:lightgray" class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>

                                        <td><input id ="num" style="text-align: right" type="hidden" name="amount1[]"  class="form-control amount1" style="font-size: 0%" value="0" />
                                        </td>

    </tr>                                       
</table>
```

when I call ajax new input what I need  is placed here within `<td ="class  priced">`

Ajax is here

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
   $(".item").change(function()
   {
   var id=$(this).val();
   var dataString = 'id='+ id;

   $.ajax
  ({

  type: "POST",
  url: "pp",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html)
  {

  $(".priced").html(html);
   } 
  });

  });

   });
 </script>
```

and ajax called file is this which is 'pp';

```
  <?php
  // Database Connection
  $username = 'root';
  $password = '';
  $db = "acccccc";
  try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=mbhost;dbname='.$db.'', $username, $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } 


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   if($_POST['id']){
   $id= $_POST['id'];
   $sql=$conn->prepare("select * from items where  '".$id."' in (c_v_id, item_id) ");
   $sql->execute();
   if($sql->rowCount() > 0){

                       $sum =     $amount= $q1 = $q2 = $am = $am1 = $am2 = $sumq =0;

                    while($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){




                        if($id == $row['c_v_id']){

                        $am = $row['amount'];
                        $q1 = $row['quantity'];

                        if($am != 0 and $q1 != 0 ){
                 $amount = $row['amount']/$row['quantity'];

                        } else{ $amount = 0;}
                        }elseif($id == $row['item_id']){

                            $am2 = $row['amount'];
                             $q2 = $row['quantity'];
                            if($am2 != 0 and $q2 != 0 ){
                            $amount = -$row['amount']/$row['quantity'];
                        }else{ $amount = 0;}
                        }
                    $sum += $amount;
                    $sumq = $q1 - $q2;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <input  title="<?php echo 'Available Quantity: '.$sumq; ?>" style="height: 30px; text-align: right" pattern="[0-9]+"  value="<?php echo $sum; ?>"
                                        maxlength="10" minlength="0"  min='0' max='50000000' type="text" name="price1[]"  class="form-control ppp" />

                    <?php 

     }else{ 


?>

<input  title="Zero Quantity" style="height: 30px; text-align: right" pattern="[0-9]+"  value="0"
                                        maxlength="10" minlength="0"  min='0' max='50000000' type="text" name="price1[]"  class="form-control ppp" />

                    <?php }


  }




 ?>
```

this code is ok for one time call...

but `td` is multiple times as  [] after jquet dynamically added rows so what should I do .. each `td` should have seperate response ... this time I call in each td but response is same for all tds..

please need an answer... thanks in advance.

Comment: One way is to give each TD a unique ID, and put the correct response for each TD by their unique ID. However the response will have to have which ID gets which HTML... your example code wont support that as is, without some changes on both ends.

Comment: How do you call multiple times ?

Comment: this td is add row dynamically jquery ...how possible .. i think loop in ajax..??

Comment: how can we have changes ID  i means id1 id2 id3 when we have add row jquery dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You should not make ajax call in loop you should make each call after the previous call succeeded but in a `setTimeout` function. Here is a code structure that will do it recursively and should solve your problem. You yourself must decide the condition to end recursive function:

```
function myAjaxCall(){
    $.ajax
({

type: "POST",
url: "pp",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".priced").html(html);

if(!/* the condition for Last ajax call*/)
  setTimeout(myAjaxCall,0);
} 
}); 

}
```

Note that another problem with your code maybe is you replace the html after each call. Instead of `$(".priced").html(html);` maybe it's better to use `$(".priced").append(html)`.

Comment: how condition put?... im new one please

Comment: I can not help you with the condition unless you provide your code completely. The condition that you figure out last ajax call. Or the last TD you want to generate. The condition that your loop already have. If it is a While Loop it already have a condition and  it is a For loop using a counter variable can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try with `jquery.on()`. Wordpress is using this function.
reed the doc:- http://api.jquery.com/on/
usage:-

```
$(document).on('click','.ajax-loaded-content',function(){ myfunc();})
```

Comment: can u give me complete code as now I have updated code which is totally completed.. @Ramesh-Kithsiri-HettiArachchi